# I work full time during the week. Can my employer also ask me to be On-call on the weekends without pay?

Tags: salary, canada, law

I work as an IT support tech at a company in British Columbia. Right now I work Monday to Friday 40 hours a week, normal daytime hours. I am paid salary, though my salary is based on the hourly wage I was making before they moved me to salary.

The industry I work in is Federally mandated, therefore provincial labour codes don't apply to us, only federal. According to the following government website, on-call employees are not considered to be working unless they are actually called in to work. https://www.canada.ca/en/employment-social-development/programs/laws-regulations/labour/interpretations-policies/hours-work.html

> While “stand-by” or “on-call” employees are common to many industries, the time spent waiting for a call is not considered work.
>
> This is borne out by case law:
>
> Richard Paré vs. S.R.J Expedite Limited (YM2727-2696): “A person who is available to work if needed, but who is not in fact needed, is not working.”
>
> Bradley H. Bell vs. LTS Solutions (YM2727-3161): “I disagree with Mr. Bell’s position that being on call and having a company cell phone and vehicle at your residence necessarily means that you are at work. ...Carrying a pager may be an inconvenience and remaining within the pagers range is undoubtedly so but this does not turn being on standby into work”.

This makes sense, though I'm not sure if it applies to my specific situation, as I work over 40 hours a week, and then am expected to "make myself available" and keep my company cell phone with me on weekends just incase something happens.

I am one of two techs supporting over 250 users and we are both working like this. I can't go to the pub to drink with friends on a friday night without feeling guilty or worrying that someone is going to call me with some emergency while I'm 5 pints in. And I can't go out camping where there's no cell reception without letting my coworker and boss know beforehand. I feel like I haven't left the office since I first walked in.

The thing is, none of the On-call work is in writing anywhere, it's more of a heavy implication that I'm just expected to be available if someone from our remote offices calls my company cell phone with an "emergency".

Admittedly I only get a call every 2-3 weekends or so but it's not the calls themselves that are the issue. At least I get paid for those. The issue is the fact that I have to be available during my "time off" for these calls and when no one does call, I'm not paid for it.

**Is there some kind of labour law in Canada that covers additional On-call hours on top of normal fulltime  hours?**

Edit for clarification: I suppose there are two outcomes I would be happy with. The first, I start getting paid for being on call. The second, I am no longer on-call every waking moment of my life. I don't mind being on-call, but I don't like working for free. So I guess my real question is, how do I achieve either of these two outcomes?

Additionally, my contract states that my hours will "remain flexible to fit company needs" not that I am to be on-call 24/7.

Also, if this question would be better served in the Law stack exchange, let me know and I will move this there.

Comment: Is knowing whether you should be paid the solution to your problem, or do you actually just want not to be on call literally all the time?

Comment: If it’s not considered work, then you leave your phone at work.

Comment: @gnasher729: This should be the case in civilised countries. However, from virolino's answer I understand that there exists other countries where the law is okay with that kind of slavery.

Comment: Most questions  that start with "Can my employer" are a better fit for https://law.stackexchange.com/ . It's also not a well formed question: Of course they can. They just did. You probably want to know EITHER whether it's legal OR  what's your options and best course of action. Please note, that these are two very different questions.

Comment: Not Canadian, but from (IT support) experience in multiple countries, on-call is paid, in one of two ways: a small fee per hour of on-call availability, or full pay for hours worked when being called upon (or both, in rare cases). Unpaid non-voluntary on-call time is massively overstepping the work-life boundary.

Comment: @NathanCooper Honestly either would be an improvement. If I had to choose though it would be the latter. I've edited my question as well.

Comment: Still, this is a legal question. belongs on law.se

Comment: @McITGuy. What I mean is you might be better off asking a different (new) question about how to go about improving your situation. Tbh you'd be even better of sharing some of your frustrations with your boss before doing that. I can imagine asking about having a rota, more clear expectations of what's expected for a response time, more clear definition of what constitutes an emergency etc.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your contract, I guess. It is also dependent on the up-time requirements of the system(s) that you are responsible for.

---

Just to give you an example. I have a friend / colleague. One of her responsibilities is to provide support to a well defined group of people.

Normally, if nothing happens, she has a job of 8hrs/day, 5 days a week. But if any need occurs, she must be available 24x7.

Is it comfortable? Definitely no. Is that her job, that she agreed with from the beginning? Definitely yes.

Is your situation similar to hers? Only you can find out. Study your contract and any other papers you have, to see what is actually expected from you.

---

> be On-call on the weekends without pay?

That is also a matter of reading your contract. Maybe the payment is (considered) already included in your salary - the same as in the case of my friend (mentioned above).

Comment: It is sad that law allows such situations to happen.

Comment: This is sad. In my country, there is a certain amount of time (and weekends) and one cannot be on call duty more than that. I don't understand your argument: I would hope the police and facebook and banking would have more than one person who have call duties? Say one week one person, next week the other.

Comment: Are you really saying that in your region everybody working in those services must be always avaible?

Comment: @virolino The police is 24/7 up, but that doesn't imply that all the officers are 24/7 working. Your logic is flawed.

Comment: Anyone brave enough to explain the downvote, please?

Comment: So does your friend have to be avaiable every day 24/7? (If yes, is she allowed to drink alcohol and go to places without phone reception?)

Comment: Yes, also in my country there are always doctors avaiable. Yet, the law forbids that an individual is available every day all the time (except for special emergency maybe like pandemics). So, your logic is flawed: The law could restrict cases like your friend's and it is sad that in some places it does not.

Comment: @guest: I tell you honestly that I do not know all the details of her contract. I guess that she is allowed to drink alcohol, as long as she can still perform her duties whenever needed (although she does not consume alcohol anyway). However, being available by phone 24x7 is mandatory for her, with reasonable exceptions: temporarily traveling through a tunnel, undergoing a medical procedure etc. It happened that she had to leave a private small party later in the evening (of a working day) to deal with a case. Even I had to called her during a weekend to ask her for some support.

Comment: @guest: what we do here is just guesswork, from different points of view. Until we see OP's contract, nothing we say is really relevant. Even small details can have great consequences.

Comment: @Roberto: as far as I know, any police officer can be called any day, at any time (in special cases), and they must report for duty (regardless of the normal schedules). I cannot be 100% sure though, as I never had that kind of job. I just know the stories of a neighbor, who had that kind of job.

Comment: In my time off, nobody can tell me that I can’t drink enough alcohol to be _not_ able to do my job. That’s why you get paid for being on call. No pay, no play.

Comment: @gnasher729: but that is actually aligned with your contract, right? I assume (from your comment) that there is no provision in your contract to be available more than 5 days/week, 8 hours/day. If my health would allow it, I might also drink alcohol in my free time, until I would be unable to even see the keyboard - also not restricted in my contract.

Comment: @gnasher729 that depends heavily on local law and what your contract says. iirc in the states you can very much be fired for cause for being drunk at a time your employer expects you to be on call, because of at-will employment. OP is in canada, but they seem to have similar jurisprudence, e.g the employer can "require" them to be on call at all times and that doesn't count as work time.

Comment: @virolino In some Countries there are employee protection laws, that would forbid that kind of contracts. Does not mean that there are no employees doing this kind of service, as long as employer and employee agree and nobody takes legal action. But the employer puts himself at risk of being sued at any time. Do you know the appropriate laws in Canada?